# how to add an action for UITextField.textFieldDidChange in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift2

I want to add this target to a UITextField in **Swift 2.2**, but i don´t know how to :-(

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)
```

Thanks!

Comment: why not use UITextFieldDelegate ?

Comment: @Shubhank Because `UITextFieldDelegate` doesn't have a method for this particular event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//use EditingChanged event it will work

```
yourTextfieldName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

Comment: `UIControlEvents.touchDown` this one worked in my case.

Answer (score 4):

( Swift 3 ) TextField *editingChanged* event. Add the TextField target to your viewDidLoad()

```
textName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

Then you have to add your code to the textFieldDidChange function to do whatever you need

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField:UITextField) {
    // your code here

}
```